# How do I sort a bunch of letters and their corresponding frequencies from a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sorting, ascii

I am trying to write a function that can analyze a string and print the letters in the string and their corresponding frequencies. This part isn't too much of a challenge because I can just use ascii_lowercase to sort through the string then the count() method available in ascii. The difficult part is sorting the frequencies so that the most frequent letter is the beginning, and the least frequent is at the end. Here is what I have written so far:

```
def analyze(codebook):
lst = []
tmp = []
for c in ascii_lowercase:
   count = codebook.count(c)
   print("('%s', %d)" % (c.upper(), count), end=" ")
   lst.append(count)
   tmp.append(c)
lst.sort()
lst.reverse()
print(lst)
print(tmp)
```

All this does is print the letter and it's corresponding frequencies in the order of the alphabet. Here is an example of the string that I am using:

```
pooiiiuuuuyyyyyttttttrrrrrrreeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqq
```

And here is an example of my desired output:

```
('Q', 10) ('W', 9) ('E', 8) ('R', 7) ('T', 6) ('Y', 5) ('U', 4) ('I', 3)

('O', 2) ('P', 1) ('A', 0) ('B', 0) ('C', 0) ('D', 0) ('F', 0) ('G', 0)

('H', 0) ('J', 0) ('K', 0) ('L', 0) ('M', 0) ('N', 0) ('S', 0) ('V', 0)

('X', 0) ('Z', 0)
```

I have also tried using collections; however, that got confusing very quickly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: to sort a list of tuples by the 2nd element use `key=lambda x: x[1]` in `sort()`or `sorted()`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre - It's marked as duplicate? here the requirement is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter`, `string.ascii_lowercase` and `sorted`

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase
s = 'pooiiiuuuuyyyyyttttttrrrrrrreeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqq'
sorted([(i.upper(),Counter(s)[i]) for i in ascii_lowercase], key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Or without using collections

```
sorted([(i.upper(), s.count(i)) for i in ascii_lowercase], key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('Q', 10),
 ('W', 9),
 ('E', 8),
 ('R', 7),
 ('T', 6),
 ('Y', 5),
 ('U', 4),
 ('I', 3),
 ('O', 2),
 ('P', 1),
 ('A', 0),
 ('B', 0),
 ('C', 0),
 ('D', 0),
 ('F', 0),
 ('G', 0),
 ('H', 0),
 ('J', 0),
 ('K', 0),
 ('L', 0),
 ('M', 0),
 ('N', 0),
 ('S', 0),
 ('V', 0),
 ('X', 0),
 ('Z', 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea with the Collections module. Use a Counter, it's their purpose:

```
from collections import Counter
s = 'pooiiiuuuuyyyyyttttttrrrrrrreeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqq'
c = Counter(s)
c
Counter({'q': 10, 'w': 9, 'e': 8, 'r': 7, 't': 6, 'y': 5, 'u': 4, 'i': 3, 'o': 2, 'p': 1})
```

It's already ordered by most frequent.

If you need the results as an ordered tuple:

```
c.most_common()

[('q', 10),
 ('w', 9),
 ('e', 8),
 ('r', 7),
 ('t', 6),
 ('y', 5),
 ('u', 4),
 ('i', 3),
 ('o', 2),
 ('p', 1)]
```

Comment: Right this made sense to me; however, I couldn't figure out how to get it into the format that I want.

Comment: How are you trying to use the results?

Comment: I want to write something that makes a "codebook" based on the frequencies of letters in a string. The most frequent is A, the second frequent is B, and so on. The format that I have in the question is both easy to read and easy to access.

Comment: Do you need to use the results programmatically, that is, later in your program? Or you want to print the results nice?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without (marginal) imports, a map is your best friend.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

s = "pooiiiuuuuyyyyyttttttrrrrrrreeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqq"
m = {}
for char in s:
    if char not in m:
        m[char] = 0
    m[char] += 1
# Make your list of tuples
res = []
for c in ascii_lowercase:
    res.append((c.upper(), m[c] if c in m else 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is follows:

```
import collections
st = "pooiiiuuuuyyyyyttttttrrrrrrreeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqq"
my_list = list(collections.Counter(list(st)).items())
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(my_list)
```

**output:**

```
[('q', 10), ('w', 9), ('e', 8), ('r', 7), ('t', 6), ('y', 5), ('u', 4), ('i', 3), ('o', 2), ('p', 1)]
```

Comment: I am in python 3 by the way. I got an attribute error: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: @P.Nar I updated it w.r.t. python3 now can you check

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a bit long, but you can modify it. Below is the code for your desired output:

```
import collections
import string
word = "pooiiiuuuuyyyyyttttttrrrrrrreeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwqqqqqqqqqq"
wordpair = collections.Counter(word)
# Getting Word Characters
wordchar = list(wordpair.keys())
wordchar = wordchar[::-1]
# Getting Word Count
wordcount = list(wordpair.values())
wordcount = wordcount[::-1]

for w,c in zip(wordchar,wordcount):
    print("('%s', %d)" % (w.upper(), c), end=" ")

for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    if char not in wordchar:
        print("('%s', %d)" % (char.upper(), 0), end=" ")
```

Output:

```
('Q', 10) ('W', 9) ('E', 8) ('R', 7) ('T', 6) ('Y', 5) ('U', 4) ('I', 3) 
('O', 2) ('P', 1) ('A', 0) ('B', 0) ('C', 0) ('D', 0) ('F', 0) ('G', 0) 
('H', 0) ('J', 0) ('K', 0) ('L', 0) ('M', 0) ('N', 0) ('S', 0) ('V', 0) 
('X', 0) ('Z', 0)
```

Comment: I am getting a random order every time that I run it.

Comment: If you change the string, it will change the order.